# Have a map with keys consisting of different types in C++

Tags: c++, types, hashmap

I currently am using a map in C++ and have a couple of values that are ints and booleans, though the majority of them are strings. I know in Java I could do something like this:

```
std::map<string, Object*> mapvar;
```

but is there an `Object` equivalent in C++?? If not, is there any way I could properly have values being a `std::string`, `int`, or `bool`?

Comment: You could use a [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: How will you compare strings to ints, to sort the contents of the map?

Comment: Boost Variant, as Nathan said, Or use [`Boost Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: @Nawaz: Boost.Any would be a disaster, since `m[Any(10)]` would never recover any existing elements!

Comment: Well I am trying to store all the member variables of a class in a map, but one of them is an int and one of them is a string. In another function inside this class, I am effectively doing some parsing and setting each of these member variables to a certain value (a value that I parsed). I will check out Boost Variant!

Comment: @user2677095 C++ is a strongly typed language. it would essentially mean, that you'd have to have a variant over all types (which is essentially boost::any or a pointer to void) and a map they key would be string to be a name right? So if you want to do these kinds of things you'd have to bascially come up with your own type system on top of the language to work properly and it's going to be expensive, but possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think the question has been changed within 5 mins. Previously it had `int` (or like) as key!

Comment: It still has int as a key.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think my concern still applies. If you make your key an `any`, then you either have to hand-write a very long complex set of casting pairs and total union orders, or otherwise you sort objects by object identity, in which case `any(10) != any(10)` (aka "Python numbering").

Comment: @KerrekSB: You didn't understand.  I was not talking about making `any` as key. The key was `int` (or like) before, and I had  suggested `any` for values *only*, as it seemed quite clear to me that key is `int`.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I realized that the key can always be a string, I don't know what I was thinking before. So all I need are the values to be bools, strings, or ints. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way you could have a `std::map` with keys that can be multiple types using the `stdlib` out of the box.

[Boost has a `variant` type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html) that functions more or less like what you want.

```
typedef boost::variant<std::string, int, bool> key_type;
std::map<key_type, Object*> mapvar
```

This map will **only accept keys that are defined in your chosen key_type**, so you could not also use, say, a `std::wstring` as a key without explicitly declaring it. This would be the advantage of using a `variant` over `any`. The latter might happily eat whatever type you send its way, while the former will give you a compile time error.

If you are going to use a `boost::variant` as your key then you need to read the boost documentation and look into what is involved in constructing `variant` objects and whether or not they have sorting pre-defined. `std::map` is built on `operator<` (unless you template it on some other sorting functor) so you'll need to make sure a working definition for your `variant` type is provided by either the library or yourself.

--

Why do you want to have such a map in the first place?

Comment: Well I am trying to store all the member variables of a class in a map, but one of them is an int and one of them is a string. In another function inside this class, I am effectively doing some parsing and setting each of these member variables to a certain value (a value that I parsed).

Comment: So wait, instead of having `class my_class { int member1; std::string member2; }` you're doing `class my_class { std::map<blah, blah> members; };`?? Why? That seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: No I had declared all of the member variables the first way. Inside one of my functions, I am declaring and initializing a map that will store all those member variables and then update their values.

Comment: Why are you putting them in a map first? Why not just update them? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @user2677095 So you are basically looking for a rudimentary runtime class type reflection? Note that types aren't enough to identify particular class members.

Comment: I could, but that would require around 20 if statements in my function in which I am doing the parsing. Inside that function, I am basically parsing a XML file with lines like, let's say, `<IPAddress>123.45.67</IPAddress>` , getting the value of 123.45.67, and then setting the member variable to 123.45.67. I could do an if statement saying `if(the key between < > ++ "IPAddress" { IPAddress = parsedvalue }`, but I'd need about 20 of them. Thought using a map would be more clear/better style.

Comment: Reading XML files usually means writing a lot of boilerplate, it's true. There are things you can do to simplify it and/or streamline it though.

Comment: Yeah, but I was told not to use a XML parser from a third-party application if possible so I just manually parsed the information. Hopefully the maps thing isn't a terrible idea given my situation, I had asked around and was recommended using maps for my situation which is why I chose to use them! Also, so assuming I created a mapvar given the way you gave me, how can I update it's info? For example, in my current code I am doing something like `*varmap[key] = value;` but I am assuming when using boost, you need to do something else because I am getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: Or is there anyway I can use boost to transfer all my member variables into a map? So if my class is named "theClass", I could do something like `boost::unordered_map<theClass,*string> varmap;`

Comment: Added to the answer a bit.

Comment: I suspect your design needs work. I'd be happy to chat about it with you in chat, but I think it is beyond the scope of this (or any other) question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86925/discussion-between-user2677095-and-caps).

Answer (score 7):

You can have several different maps, and hide the lookup in overloaded functions:

```
std::map<int, Object>           map_int;
std::map<std::string, Object>   map_string;

Object& lookup(int Key)
{ return map_int[Key]; }

Object& lookup(std::string Key)
{ return map_string[Key]; }
```

Now all your lookups kan be done with `lookup(key)`.

Answer (score 2):

> *"but is there an Object equivalent in C++??"*

No, there isn't such thing in standard C++. [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) may provide something similar perhaps.

> *"If not, is there any way I could properly have keys being a string, int, or boolean?"*

There's stuff like [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html), but I'm not sure, if you could use them as a key in a `std::map`.

Sounds a bit you're asking for a XY-Problem. Explain your actual use case please.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I realized that the key can always be a string, I don't know what I was thinking before. So all I need are the values to be bools, strings, or ints. Sorry for the confusion!