# How to add pair vector as a value in std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

```
std::map<Type, vector<std::pair<Value, Integer>>>
```

I want to create a map like above, so purpose is if i have a lot of dataType and values scrambled, then I want to first check for a dataType and then values of such dataType and then number of time these values occurred.
For eg:

```
DataType: int ,char, string 
Values : 23,54,24,78,John, oliver, word ,23
```

so i want to store something like

```
(int,<(23,2),(54,1),(24,1)>)
```

similarly for other datatype

Answer (score 2):

**Using a value which can hold various types**

For `Value` You need a class which allows storing multiple value types.

There is no such class in standard c++ (until c++17, not included). You need a library such as [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html).
(Boost::variant will become std::variant in c++17)

In your case, you can declare the Value type with:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, char, std::string> Value;
```

The map declaration will be:

```
std::unordered_map<Value, int> myMap;
```

**Tested example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeindex>

//typdedef the variant class as it is quite complicated
typedef boost::variant<int, char, std::string> Value;

//The map container declaration
std::map<Value, int> myMap;

int main()
    {
    //insert elements to the map
    myMap[boost::variant<int>(23)]++;
    myMap[boost::variant<int>(23)]++;
    myMap[boost::variant<int>(23)]++;
    myMap[boost::variant<int>(54)]++;
    myMap[boost::variant<int>(24)]++;

    myMap[boost::variant<std::string>("John")]++;
    myMap[boost::variant<std::string>("John")]++;
    myMap[boost::variant<char>(60)]++;

    //iterate all integers
    std::cout << "Integers:\n";
    for (auto it=myMap.cbegin(); it!=myMap.cend(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->first.type() == typeid(int))
        {
            std::cout << "int=" << boost::get<int>(it->first) << " count=" << it->second << "\n";            
        }
        else if(it->first.type() == typeid(std::string))
        {
            std::cout << "string=\"" << boost::get<std::string>(it->first) << "\" count=" << it->second << "\n";            
        }
        else if(it->first.type() == typeid(char))
        {
            std::cout << "char='" << boost::get<char>(it->first) << "' count=" << it->second << "\n";            
        }
    }
}
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B6yttcO9sZJUnKkS

Comment: A link to documentation/example usage of `boost::variant` would be nice

Comment: I think the OP wants to use different `dataType` as the map's key instead of int, he will have three types of `dataType`: int, char, string. Probably more similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993839/have-a-map-with-keys-consisting-of-different-types-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the answer was heavily reworked!

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am not looking to store something  like myMap[typeid(int)].emplace_back(boost::variant<int>(23),2);  what I want is when ever I encounter value 23 it should increase the frequency so like if 23 is encounter for the first time it should store (23 ,1) on next encounter it should become (23,2) an so on. Hope this give a more clear picture.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Does this answer your question now?